# How to prove this series converges...

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Beloved community,

Does the following series converge?

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \left(\sqrt[n]{n} - \sqrt[n+1]{n+1}\right)$$

According to Wolfram Alpha, it does by the Comparison Test. However, after thinking about it long and hard, I still haven't found any series to compare it to.

Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: It's a telescoping series.

Comment: @carmichael561 gee whizz, I should have written out a few terms; it's fairly obvious. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\sqrt[k]k-\sqrt[k+1]{k+1}\right)=1-\sqrt2+\sqrt2-\sqrt[3]3+\sqrt[3]3-\sqrt[4]4+\ldots+\sqrt[n]n-\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}=$$

$$=1-\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

Comment: This is perfect. thanks. from now on, I will write out the first few terms. lol.

Comment: @MitchBaker You're welcome, and great idea.